# How to end a cron started script?

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

I start a script via cron which works fine. But when i then try to end that script via cron (either `killall` / `pkill` / `pgrep` does work) nothing happens.

If i let cron try to kill it or try it my own doesn't do a difference.
The only way to stop it seems to be `htop` and then F9 (sigterm).

So, How to **end** a cron-started script?

My scripts starts with `#!bin/bash` and cron starts it by `./path/script.sh`.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What about `pkill -term`?

Comment: @muru thanks for the suggestion. But which "terminal" should i name then ? If i understood it right, pkill -t (term[inal]) points on a specific terminal !?? ty

Comment: No, given a signal like SIGKILL, SIGTERM, etc, you can use the name with `pkill`: `pkill -kill`, `pkill -term`, etc.

Comment: ty again, but sadly: pkill -term myscript.sh doesn't do the trick either.

Comment: what should work anyway is killing it by its pid; find its pid with `ps -ef`, look for the scriptname, then: `kill <pid>`

Comment: Thank you a lot, that is pretty close to a complete solution. Something like : start.pseudo.code: cron * x * * * ps -ef | grep myscript.sh | grep just.the.PID && kill PID  /end pseudo code, should do the trick. :-)

Comment: using `ps -ef` is how I use to toggle scripts on/off (but then using python :))

Comment: Thanks for your help, Jacob Vlijm, sorry that i didn't tested you idea earlier, to let you know that it strangly didn't worked without the -f option in this special case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What should work anyway is to kill it by its pid:

- run `ps -ef` (or `ps -efww` if the lines are too long to read the end)
- find the scriptname, and you will have its pid
- kill it with:

  ```
  kill <pid>
  ```

  (mind you: not `pkill`, which is to used as `pkill <application>`, *not* as `pkill <pid>`)

#### Note:

Using the command:

```
ps -ef | grep testscript
```

will list two processes; the one you are looking for and the *search process itself* that you are running, e.g.:

```
jacob     4183  3647  0 11:22 pts/10   00:00:00 python3 /home/jacob/Bureaublad/testscript.py
jacob     4202  4189  0 11:22 pts/25   00:00:00 grep --color=auto testscript
```

which means that you would have to use e.g.:

```
ps -ef | grep <scriptname> | grep -v grep
> jacob     4183  3647  0 11:22 pts/10   00:00:00 python3 /home/jacob/Bureaublad/testscript.py
```

To only find the line you need.

Unlike the `pgrep` command, that filters itself out of the list, as pointed out [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74190): :

```
pgrep -f testscript
> 4183
```

That means that using `pgrep -f <scrptname>`as suggested by @muru is the better way, for more than one reason.

Comment: `pgrep` is still a much better option than `ps | grep`.

Comment: @muru That may be true, but - as already mentioned - pgrep does not work in this case.

Comment: @tuxaddict Have you tried `pgrep -f`?

Comment: @muru YES !!! That did the trick ! Thank you muru. Even pkill -f myscript.sh works now :-) I sadly have to say, that finding the PID out and then do a pkill <pid> suprisingly didn't worked either. But the -f option is the solution. :-)

Comment: @tuxaddict `pkill` is for use of with the *name*, `kill` is to be used with the *pid*: `pkill <application>`, `kill <pid>`

Comment: Just to note: it is possible to use PIDs with pgrep/pkill, depending on the version. Newer versions support reading a PID from a PID file, such as those often created by services.

Comment: I see. However, it does nothing here (yet) in 14.10.

Comment: @JacobVlijm To prevent `grep` appearing in the running processes, use something like `grep [t]estscript`. Here, the regex searches for exactly the same thing as before, but the process will include the literal `[]`, and hence will not match the regex.